# Inserting a Node Into a Sorted Doubly Linked List In order

Tags: c++, insert, nodes

I have code for inserting a node into a linked list. The requirements are that the code eliminates duplicates from the input, and puts them in order. It passes multiple test cases but not all of them. If anyone has any insights it would be very helpful. Thanks.

```
DoublyLinkedListNode* sortedInsert(DoublyLinkedListNode* head, int data){

    DoublyLinkedListNode* temp = new DoublyLinkedListNode(data);

    if (head == NULL)  
    {   
        return temp;   
    }

    if (head->data == data)  
    {  
        return head;  
    }

    if (head->data > data)   
    {   
         temp->next = head;          
         return temp;   
    }

    if(head->next != NULL)  
    {    
         head->next = sortedInsert(head->next, data);   
    }

    else  
    {       
        head->next = temp;  
    }

    return head;

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that calls this.

Comment: You have a memory leak on all cases that don't add temp to the list. This is worsened by the recursive call.

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve]. 2) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Is it called `DoublyLinkedListNode` to make competitors confused?

Comment: The best way to debug a linked list is with pictures. Draw the list as it appears on entry, then follow the instructions in your code **exactly** to traverse and modify the list. If when you find yourself drawing something silly, you've found a bug. If you can't draw the test list because it goes on for miles and miles, you might want to make sure you aren't recursing your way to Automatic storage exhaustion.

Comment: You should only allocate a new node if it is not a duplicate.  You can have pointers to nodes without allocating memory.

Comment: The insertion process may be more efficient by iteration (a `while` loop) rather than recursion.  Each recursive call occupies more space on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Whole your function can be written as:

```
DoublyLinkedListNode* sortedInsert(DoublyLinkedListNode* head, int data)
{
    if( head and head->data <= data ) {
        if( head->data < data ) 
           head->next = sortedInsert(head->next, data);
        return head;
    }
    DoublyLinkedListNode* temp = new DoublyLinkedListNode(data);
    temp->next = head;
    return temp;
}
```

it is shorter, simpler and does not have memory leak. Btw it is usually not a good idea to call single linked list node as `DoublyLinkedListNode` and also it is not a good idea to return raw pointer to dynamically allocated memory, use a smart pointer instead.

Comment: Why use `and` instead of `&&`? It just confuses everyone who hasn't heard of alternative operator representations.

Comment: @FeiXiang I think in 21th century it is shame to use trigraphs and &&  || etc. Programming languages are for humans.

Comment: Well, something like Java or Python might be better suited for you then :)

Comment: @FeiXiang thanks, but I can decide that by myself without your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
DoublyLinkedListNode* sortedInsert(DoublyLinkedListNode* head, int data) {
    DoublyLinkedListNode* temp=head;
    DoublyLinkedListNode* newNode=(DoublyLinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(DoublyLinkedListNode));
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    newNode->prev=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)                  //If head is empty
    {
        head=newNode;
        return head;
    }
    while(temp->data<data && temp->next!=NULL)     //Point to the node that is greater than data
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(temp->prev==NULL)             //If the node to be inserted is first-Testcase1
    {
        newNode->next=temp;
        temp->prev=newNode;
        head=newNode;
    }
    else if(temp->next==NULL && temp->data<data)     //If the node to be inserted is last Test Case-2
    {

        newNode->prev=temp;    
        temp->next=newNode;
    }
    else                          //If the node to be inserted is middle Test Case-3
        {
            newNode->next=temp;
        newNode->prev=temp->prev;
        temp->prev->next=newNode;
        temp->prev=newNode;
        }
         return head;
}
```